# Taylor series up to first order

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I have an expression of the form:

$$\frac{1}{1+f(x)}$$ which I want to simplify by employing Taylor series up to linear order. I know that in general:

$$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+....$$   if $|x|<1$ or $|x|<<1$?

I want to know whether it is also applicable to the case above? i.e., $$\frac{1}{1+f(x)}=[1+f(x)]^{-1}=1-f(x)+f^2(x)-f^3(x)+....$$ with the condition that $|f(x)|<1$ or $f(x)<<1$ ? for any $f(x)$. A linear order approximation would yield $$\frac{1}{1+f(x)}=1-f(x)$$ which is a reasonable approximation if $f(x)<<1$.

Comment: You can as long as $|f(x)|<1$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it just $|f(x)|<1$ or $|f(x)|<<1$?

Comment: The series $1-f(x)+f^2(x)-f^3(x)+....$ converges as long as $|f(x)|<1$, but if you only use first order approximation $1-f(x)$ then you need to make sure $|f(x)|<<1$, otherwise the approximation would be very imprecise.

Comment: @Ricky Thanks :)